# How to delete a image in firebase storage using the url of the image in react native?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-storage

How to delete a image in firebase storage using the url of the image in react native?

this is the structure of the data

```
list {
  ["https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/testes-109.appspot.com/o/photos%2FmdWs20BYhSdR4XIePdpBL9szC7i2%2F79337645-7aa6-4fa3-ab29-9dae6f41bc6?alt=media&token=a9cc2795-f118-485c-94b9-cdf0c083eb2a", "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/testes-109.appspot.com/o/photos%2FmdWs20BYhSdR4XIePdpBL9szC7i2%2F79337645-7aa6-4fa3-ab29-9dabe6f41bc6?alt=media&token=a9cc2795-f118-48c-94b9-cdf0c83eb2a", ],
   }
```

i tried this

```
  <FlatList
        data={list}
        renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
          return (
            <View >
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.deleteImage(item)} >

                <Image source={{ uri: item }} style={{ width:100, height: 100 }} />


              </TouchableOpacity >
            </View>
          )
        }}

      />


deleteImage = (item) => {

    alert(item)

    var desertRef = item;

    desertRef.delete()
    .then(function() {

      console.log('File deleted successfully')

    }).catch(function(error) {

       console.log('Uh-oh, an error occurred!')

    });
  }
```

but got this error

desertRef.delete is not a fuction. (in 'desertRef.delete()', 'desertRef.delete' is undefined

Answer (score 2):

create storage object with your firebaseConfig

```
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const storage = getStorage(app);
export default storage;
```

You need to use the following function to delete it from storage.

```
import { deleteObject, ref } from "firebase/storage";
import storage from "<your storage file path where you export it>";

export const deleteFromStorage = (file: string | undefined) => {
  if (file) {

       let pictureRef = ref(storage, file);
    deleteObject(pictureRef)
      .then(() => {
        alert("Picture is deleted successfully!");
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
}
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import storage from '@react-native-firebase/storage';

const imageRef = storage().refFromURL( YOUR_IMAGE_URL_HERE );
imageRef.delete();
```